# How to invert the output of 74138 IC?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, decoder

[image]

I have this incomplete circuit. I want to know if there is any other way ,except inverting each decoder's output or making changes in any other IC, to make the desired output be H and the others L?

Comment: It would be nice to know what you're trying to accomplish, but an 74HC238 (eg) is an active high version of the '138.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no other way to invert the outputs.

Answer (score 1):

> How to invert the output of 74138 IC?

Get hold of a 74238 chip - it is the same as the 74138 but its outputs are the opposite polarity. I believe you can still buy them so good luck.

> I want to know if there is any other way ,except inverting each
>   decoder's output or making changes in any other IC

Just change the 138 for a 238!

The data sheet below was (re) published in 2018 so I guess they are available: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I am obligated to use 74138 in my project.

Comment: So when you said “in any other IC” what did you actually mean?

Comment: The other ICs in the image. Because I'm thinking of changing the 2 second level 7408 ICs to 7400 although it is not permissible in the project. And I actually don't want to connect each decoder output to an inverter

Comment: Might be a language thing.... the word “except” was at the start of the 2nd half of that sentence and that usually means everything after that word is not allowed hence I read the word “other” as negating that exception for the chip itself but not so for the other chips. In other words that sentence appeared to grant permission for considering a chip replacement for just the 138. See what I mean?

Comment: Well it might be possible to come up with equivalent logic, but to even try that we would need a real schematic diagram not whatever that thing purports to be. Seriously, contender (for the remarkably low bar) of worst 'schematic' on SO.

Comment: @Andyaka I got it. When I asked the question I thought that there may be a way in changing the enabling inputs of the decoder so that only one of the outputs will be high while the others are low. Is there any?

Comment: @DanMills I know that the scheme is terrible but I am still new in this stuff. I am just looking for a way to solve my problem.

Comment: No either change the chip to a 238 or use inverters on the output.